# Rewrite Rule from Apache to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

Can anyone help me with rewriting this?
I have these rules:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*) /api/prerender/$2 [P,L]
```

And I need that to be rewritten to nginx.

Basically, let's assume this URL

```
http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/item/123
```

should be rewritten to

```
http://example.com/api/prerender/?_escaped_fragment_=/item/123
```

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location / { 
  if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest") {   
    rewrite ^/(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*) /api/prerender/$2 break; 
  } 
}
```